# Taglib sharp saving ONLY ID3v2

Tags: save, id3, taglib-sharp, id3v2

I'm new using TagLib sharp. I'm trying to save ONLY an specific version of the tag inside the file. Everytime I save the tag both ID3v1 and ID3v2 get created. Is there a way to stop this from happening? Can I choose which one I want to save. The save function doesn't take any arguments, so any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

These tags are added for convenience when the `File` object is created.  The correct way to remove newly created tags is to perform the following command before calling `Save`:

```
file.RemoveTags (file.TagTypes & ~file.TagTypesOnDisk);
```

[Source](https://github.com/mono/taglib-sharp/blob/master/src/TagLib/Mpeg/AudioFile.cs#L37)

Answer (score 3):

Thank you Brian.
The C# "& ~" syntax is not that obvious for VB.NET users:

```
file.RemoveTags(file.TagTypes And Not file.TagTypesOnDisk)
```

@user1098787:
If you want to write a specific id3v2 version, you can use this commands

```
TagLib.Id3v2.Tag.DefaultVersion = 3
TagLib.Id3v2.Tag.ForceDefaultVersion = True
```

Possible values for DefaultVersion are 2 (id3v2.2), 3 (id3v2.3) or 4 (id3v2.4)